# Floating point errors in custom Vector2D class

Tags: c++, game-development

I've written a custom Vector2D class for a game I'm making. As near as I can tell, my rotation function is mathematically correct, and yet I'm getting strange output when testing.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong using floating point numbers, but I'm lost as to diagnosing and solving these issues.

Here are all of the relevant functions for my testing code:

```
float Vector2D::Magnitude() const
{
    return sqrtf((X * X) + (Y * Y));
}

float Vector2D::Angle() const
{
    float rad = atanf(Y / X);
    float degrees = rad * 180.0f / PI;
    return degrees;
}

void Vector2D::Rotate(float degrees)
{
    float angle = degrees * PI / 180.0f;

    float s = sinf(angle);
    float c = cosf(angle);

    float newX = (c * X) - (s * Y);
    float newY = (s * X) + (c * Y);

    X = newX;
    Y = newY;
}
```

And my testing setups:

```
Vector2D c(1.0f, 1.0f);

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
{
    c.Rotate(90);

    std::cout << "Angle: " << c.Angle() << " Magnitude: " << c.Magnitude() << " X: " << c.X << " Y: " << c.Y << std::endl;
}
```

1.0f, 1.0f as X and Y give this output:

```
Angle: -45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: -1 Y: 1
Angle: 45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: -1 Y: -1
Angle: -45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: 1 Y: -1
Angle: 45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: 1 Y: 1
Angle: -45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: -1 Y: 1
Angle: 45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: -1 Y: -1
Angle: -45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: 1 Y: -1
Angle: 45 Magnitude: 1.41421 X: 1 Y: 1
```

When testing the above code with 1.0f, 0.0f as X and Y, this is the output I get:

```
Angle: -90 Magnitude: 1 X: -4.37114e-08 Y: 1
Angle: 5.00896e-06 Magnitude: 1 X: -1 Y: -8.74228e-08
Angle: -90 Magnitude: 1 X: 1.31134e-07 Y: -1
Angle: 1.00179e-05 Magnitude: 1 X: 1 Y: 1.74846e-07
Angle: -90 Magnitude: 1 X: -2.18557e-07 Y: 1
Angle: 1.50269e-05 Magnitude: 1 X: -1 Y: -2.62268e-07
Angle: -90 Magnitude: 1 X: 3.0598e-07 Y: -1
Angle: 2.00358e-05 Magnitude: 1 X: 1 Y: 3.49691e-07
```

Neither of these are correct. My expected values for 1.0f, 1.0f:

```
Angle: 90 Magnitude: 1 X: 1 Y: 1
Angle: 180 Magnitude: 1 X: -1 Y: -1
Angle: 270 Magnitude: 1 X: 1 Y: -1
Angle: 360 (or 0): Magnitude: 1 X: 1 Y: 1
```

And so on for the next 4 iterations of the loop.

For 1.0f, 0.0f, the output should be:

Angle: 90 Magnitude: 1 X: 0 Y: 1
Angle: 180 Magnitude: 1 X: -1 Y: 0 
Angle: 270 Magnitude: 1 X: 0 Y: -1
Angle: 360 (or 0) Magnitude: 1 X: 1 Y: 0

If anyone would be kind enough to explain what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate the guidance.

Comment: I think you want `atan2f(y, x)` not `atanf(y / x)`, atanf just doesn't do what you think it does. This more a math error than a programming error. Other errors look like rounding errors to me, *but you didn't actually say what you think the errors are*, fix that.

Comment: Why are they incorrect? Do you mean they aren't exactly `0`? By the way, you should be using [`std::atan2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2).

Comment: May be you can also tell what are your expected values.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the problem was not in my math (aside from the atan2f versus atan problem).
The problem was how I was using rotation in another area of my code.

Thanks for your help, I should have checked that my code breaking with the Vector class was correct.